# Black triangles in mesh

Tags: mesh

[image]

Hi all, I'm super new to Blendr (as in, day one) and I'm trying to edit a pre-existing mesh. I've managed to get through quite a bit of the learning curve but I can not seem to get rid of the two black triangles pictured here. I've tried going through so much of the forum for similar issues but so much terminology is brand new as well --

Long story short, can anyone give me a tip on what I'm looking at and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you sure that isn't just the texture? If you select all the vertices with `a` and then do `spacebar` > `tris to quad`. If the black stays it's definitely your texture.

Comment: @Sidar I'm an idiot, it's my texture. Thanks!

Comment: Not an idiot, but a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often times faces appear darker if their normals are flipped. In computer games these faces are usually not rendered. Blender however makes sure that they are and hints to the user that the normals are flipped. To test if it's a normal issue you should check enable `backface culling` in the 3D views properties panel

[image]

Your faces however seem pitch black thus this could imply a few things:

- Faces are assigned to a material which is pitch black
- Faces are mapped to a black/empty region in your texture
- You're seeing the vertex colors assigned to the vertices.

edit:

[image]

Comment: Thank you again. I can't find anything in my texture that lines up with this at all, even after experimenting with multiple parts of it. I deleted the swath of the mesh just before this that can be seen below the triangles, however those stubbornly refuse to part ways.

Comment: if possible can you upload the file ( if it's all legal)

Comment: Yes! Let me uh -- figure out how to --

https://www.dropbox.com/s/67k1oiwssrn53lj/giorno.blend?dl=0

Hope that's okay! Sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9br7xn5k07dkh2/giorno.png?dl=0

Here is the texture as well, just in case.

Comment: @Midi Those faces are mapped to black/empty space, check my edit

Comment: (sort of, anyway)

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer please accept it so it doesn't linger.