# Some triangles in imported PLY with Color Attribute appearing dark

Tags: import, artifacts

I'm new to Blender, and I was trying to render a model from the game Stormworks, a .ply file. Having imported it, and getting stuck, given the learning curve, I consulted [this guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2007958919), however, the small helicopter I was trying to render appeared with some dark artefacts:

[image: Helicopter with some triangles dark]

The darkness doesn't seem to be tied to the parts used in Stormworks, or any theme for that matter. I tried many things, like [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108252/black-triangles-in-mesh) said to do tris-to-quads, which didn't change anything, there was also an answer regarding backface culling, but I can't work out how that works, given that person had a wildly different looking version of Blender to me.

If anyone knows how to fix this, it'd be really useful, thank you.

Comment: It might be doubled geometry. Polygons resting on the exact same plane will produce shading artifacts, usually zebra stripes but it can also produce dark areas. Check if you don't have multiple objects at the same place in space, or if you don'th have doubled geometry in edit mode

Comment: It's only one object imported, could that change the solution?